# IE 11 & FireFox not encoding the query string in the URL, but chrome does

Tags: node.js, internet-explorer, url, query-string

I am writing a node.js application. In which I am trying to encode the url that would show in the address bar of the browser.
For an example: `http:/www.abcdefghjs.com?q=This%20is%20good`

Chrome shows the url in the address bar with the encoding as below or above url

```
http:/www.abcdefghjs.com?q=This%20is%20good
```

IE 11 & FireFox does not showing up the %20 for space, the url in the address bar as below:

```
http:/www.abcdefghjs.com?q=This is good
```

Any sort of help is appreciated to fix this for IE11 & Firefox.

NOTE: I have tried both the node.js function `encodeURIComponent()` and `encodeURI()`. But noot working in IE11 and FireFox

Answer (score 1):

Just as chrispytoes says, it's a browser behavior by design and there's nothing we can do about it. Besides, we can use **Fiddler** to track the url request. As we can see in the **Inspectors**, IE actually sends the encoded request though it shows un-encoded in address bar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it actually affecting your application? Could be that Firefox is just showing it to you un-encoded but actually sends the request encoded.

Also, how are you navigating to the URL? Are you setting it with JS or are you just clicking a link?

Edit: From a quick google search, for Firefox, it looks like when the URL is already encoded, it displays as decoded in the address bar. If it is not already encoded it will show encoded.

Comment: It's not actually affecting the application. but wondering why only Firefox is un-encoded but Chrome.
navigation is setting up with JS.

Comment: @PaulGregory Just the behavior of the browser, nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the FF as you said I copy pasted the URL to a notepad , seems that is already encoded. But I did the same in IE seems it is not encoded